# how do i expand navbar content and change navbar text_content simultaneously using jquery?

Tags: jquery

whenever the nav bar is clicked it will change the navbar text content and the navbar will expand simultaneously but the expand is not working. Can i get some hints?

```js
$("nav").click(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html() == 'chemistry' ? 'STUDENTS' : 'chemistry');
  $('.student-list').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="header-bar">
  <div id="group-name" class="subject">chemistry</div>
  <ul class="student-list" style={display: "none";}>
    <li>jai</li>
    <li>lokesh</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're replacing the entire HTML content of `nav` tag. But you wanted to replace the contents of `#group-name` only.

A better approach would be to find the `#group-name`, and replace the HTML content of it only.

```js
$("nav").click(function() {
  var groupName = $(this).find('#group-name');
  groupName.html(groupName.html() == 'chemistry' ? 'STUDENTS' : 'chemistry');
  $('.student-list').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="header-bar">
  <div id="group-name" class="subject">chemistry</div>
  
  <ul class="student-list">
    <li>jai</li>
    <li>lokesh</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: but the bind function was depricated in jquery 3.0 above

Comment: @KundanKumar -- I didn't mention to use `bind` function anywhere.

Comment: actually i want that when anywhere on nav the user click the above function should work, do i have any other method other than this (changing the whole content of html)

Comment: yes i know that you didn't used it but i was just saying that it was removed

Comment: thanks bro for the hint its working now, i have used the children() tag with the nav